# Time and memory efficient way to find intersection between pairs from a large list (R)

Tags: r, matrix, memory, memory-management

I have a list of length N, and each list element is 10 character strings sampled from some bigger group. I want to find every pair of elements that are very similar, say with >=8 strings in common. **I can do this alright for N<10,000 using `crossprod`, but I run out of memory for larger N**.

Here's an example where N=1000, resulting in 6 very similar pairs:

```
# make list x
set.seed(1)
N = 1000
x = lapply(1:N, function(x) sample(letters, 10))
names(x) = as.character(1:length(x))

# find pairwise intersect, store in square matrix N_intersect
N_intersect = x %>% stack() %>% table() %>% crossprod()
diag(N_intersect) = 0
N_intersect[lower.tri(N_intersect)] = 0

# find when N_intersect is over some threshold
result = which(N_intersect > 8, arr.ind = T)

result
    ind ind
111 111 375
705 705 708
48   48 771
317 317 797
566 566 883
705 705 958
```

However since the output of `crossprod` is an NxN matrix, it quickly goes out of memory for large N. I know there are sparse methods for crossprod, but that only seems to reduce the memory by around ~30%.

The thing is, the number of highly similar elements is usually super small, like 1/1000 pairs. So **I don't need to store the big square matrix from crossprod, but I can't think of a memory-efficient method that can do this quickly.** I could just check each pair of elements in a for loop, but that takes a few hours.

Comment: Note, you are not supposed to edit solutions into the question. But strictly speaking you did not, so I will let this pass....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps anyone.

I found a method to detect similar pairs in my list `x` that runs in approximately the same time as `crossprod`, but most important it doesn't go out of memory. I did this by taking the input to crossprod, `x %>% stack() %>% table()`, an Nxm matrix where m is the number of possible characters. m=26 in the example above, since I'm using letters. Each row represents a list element in `x`, with 1s denoting letters in the element and 0s letters not in it.

My question is then "which pairs of rows have at least 9 shared columns with 1s?" I answered this for each row by 1) subsetting columns and 2) rowSums. This method is `f.new` and I compare it to the old method `f.crossprod`:

```
f.crossprod = function(x, threshold) {
  # find intersection of each pair elements with crossprod
  # store in upper triangular square matrix
  N_intersect = x %>% stack() %>% table() %>% crossprod()
  diag(N_intersect) = 0
  N_intersect[lower.tri(N_intersect)] = 0
  
  # find when N_intersect is over some threshold
  result = which(N_intersect >= threshold, arr.ind = T) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    `colnames<-`(c("row", "col"))
  rownames(result) = NULL
  return(result)
}

f.new = function(x, threshold) {
  x2 = t(table(stack(x)))
  result = list()
  for (ii in 3:nrow(x2)) {
    ia = which(x2[ii,]>0)
    cands = which(rowSums(x2[1:(ii-1),ia]) >= threshold)
    result[[ii]] = data.frame(row=cands, col=rep(ii, length(cands)))
  }
  result = do.call(rbind, result) %>% filter(!row==col)
  rownames(result) = NULL
  return(result)
}
```

I can see they both return the same results:

```
set.seed(1)
N = 1000
x = lapply(1:N, function(x) sample(letters, 10))
names(x) = as.character(1:length(x))

r1 = f.new(x, 9)
r2 = f.crossprod(x, 9)
identical(r1, r2)

> TRUE
```

The timing is similar, although f.new is slightly faster for N>5000. Most importantly f.new has no problem with N>20000:

[image]